# Will the private Belize Foundation have dividends from NYSE withheld at 4% or 30%?

Tags: irs

Will the private Belize Foundation have dividends from NYSE withheld at 4% or 30%?

I have heard that foreign foundations have dividends withheld at 4%, but Belize does not have DTAA with US.